# Do carriers move across a p-n junction at $0\ \mathrm{K}$?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Often a band diagram is used to explain what happens when two pieces of the same semiconductor, one p-doped, one n-doped, are put together. I am a little confused about it, so here is my question.

Initially and at $0\ \mathrm{K}$, the surplus carriers should be confined to their respective acceptor and donor levels, e.g. the flatband diagram would look like follows:

[image: this figure]

Now, there are no free carriers in the system and thus, the electrons from the donor level should not be able to recombine with the holes from the acceptor levels due to spatial detachment. Of course, provided some temperature, the acceptor and donor carriers would ionize and free carriers would be at disposal for recombination and thus, a depletion zone would form. But at 0K it seems to me that this should not happen. In reality, would a depletion zone be formed anyway somehow (are there other relevant physics taking action)?

Comment: Since you can't actually get to 0K, this is not a real issue. So, it might take some time to form a depletion region, but it will form.

Comment: I like this question because at an interview, I was asked this very question, and I answered with a "no". But the interviewers said that even at $\mathrm{0K}$, doped semiconductors interact with each other and form a depletion region. I can't say I was very convinced by their answer. Looking for an answer here.

Comment: In the last paragraph, what do you mean by *spatial detachment*?

Comment: @sammygerbil What I mean is that they cannot be at the same position because they are confined to their respective acceptor/donor level. Of course the uncertainty relation allows some movement, but I presume there is no sufficient overlap between the wave functions of the electron and hole closest to the junction.

Comment: Acceptor/donor levels are *energy levels*, not positions within the material.

Comment: @sammygerbil Sure, but they originate from the dopend and thus should have a fixed position within the semiconductor crystal.

Comment: If donor electrons can get into the conduction band, they can move around in the crystal.

Comment: @sammygerbil But they can't @ 0K, that's my point.

Comment: Yes that is the point of your question. But it is not the point of your statement about *spatial detachment*.

Comment: I believe that even at 0K, a depletion region will form, due to the "tunnel"effect, or the "probabilistic" energy distribution.